# Import Button Error java.security.accesscontrolexception access denied (java.util.propertypermission user.dir read) in Win7 64bit jre7 & jdk1.7.0_25

Tags: java, permissions, applet, policy

I am using 
windows 7 64 bit (has also program files (x86) ),
jre 7  &  jdk1.7.0_25

I got following error while accesing my applet file in the IE8 (8.0.7600.16385)

java.security.accesscontrolexception access denied (java.util.propertypermission user.dir read)

However i can get to my next page/results but i can't passby/handle this exception

The same file works in windows 7 32 bit when i changed jav.policy file with following.

```
// Standard extensions get all permissions by default

grant codeBase "file:${java.home}/lib/ext/*" {
     permission java.util.PropertyPermission "user.dir", "read";
     permission java.security.AllPermission;
};

// default permissions granted to all domains

grant codeBase "file:C:/Inetpub/wwwroot/applets/*" {
permission java.util.PropertyPermission "user.dir", "read";
permission java.security.AllPermission;
};

grant codeBase "file:C:/Inetpub/wwwroot/applets/ordered.xslt" {
permission java.util.PropertyPermission "user.dir", "read";
permission java.security.AllPermission;
};

grant codeBase "file:C:/Inetpub/wwwroot/applets/nonOrdered.xslt" {
permission java.util.PropertyPermission "user.dir", "read";
permission java.security.AllPermission;
};

grant codeBase "file:C:/Inetpub/wwwroot/applets/common.xsl" {
permission java.util.PropertyPermission "user.dir", "read";
permission java.security.AllPermission;
};

grant {
permission java.util.PropertyPermission "user.dir", "read";
permission java.security.AllPermission;
};

//grant { 
     // Allows any thread to stop itself using the java.lang.Thread.stop()
     // method that takes no argument.
     // Note that this permission is granted by default only to remain
     // backwards compatible.
     // It is strongly recommended that you either remove this permission
     // from this policy file or further restrict it to code sources
     // that you specify, because Thread.stop() is potentially unsafe.
     // See "http://java.sun.com/notes" for more information.
//     permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "stopThread";

     // allows anyone to listen on un-privileged ports
//     permission java.net.SocketPermission "localhost:1024-", "listen";

     // "standard" properies that can be read by anyone

//     permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.version", "read";
//     permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.vendor", "read";
//     permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.vendor.url", "read";
//     permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.class.version", "read";
//     permission java.util.PropertyPermission "os.name", "read";
//     permission java.util.PropertyPermission "os.version", "read";
//     permission java.util.PropertyPermission "os.arch", "read";
//     permission java.util.PropertyPermission "file.separator", "read";
//     permission java.util.PropertyPermission "path.separator", "read";
//     permission java.util.PropertyPermission "line.separator", "read";

//     permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.specification.version", "read";
//     permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.specification.vendor", "read";
//     permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.specification.name", "read";

//     permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.vm.specification.version", "read";
//     permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.vm.specification.vendor", "read";
//     permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.vm.specification.name", "read";
//     permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.vm.version", "read";
//     permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.vm.vendor", "read";
//     permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.vm.name", "read";
//  permission java.net.SocketPermission "softag2:1024-65535","connect,accept,resolve,listen";  
//  permission java.net.SocketPermission "softag2:80", "connect,accept,resolve,listen"; 
//};
```

Comment: Digitally sign the applet.  It will be faster (slow maybe to set it up, but a fraction of a second to do during the build).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I myself solved it by replacing my **java.policy** file by following and it worked on several machines, If anyone coming around here may get help

```
/* AUTOMATICALLY GENERATED ON Tue Dec 10 14:15:46 PKT 2013*/
/* DO NOT EDIT */

grant codeBase "file:/C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/New%20Folder%20(2)/Java/jre6/lib/ext/*" {
  permission java.security.AllPermission;
};

grant codeBase "file:/C:/Windows/Sun/Java/lib/ext/*" {
  permission java.security.AllPermission;
};

grant {
  permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "stopThread";
  permission java.net.SocketPermission "localhost:1024-", "listen";
  permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.version", "read";
  permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.vendor", "read";
  permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.vendor.url", "read";
  permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.class.version", "read";
  permission java.util.PropertyPermission "os.name", "read";
  permission java.util.PropertyPermission "os.version", "read";
  permission java.util.PropertyPermission "os.arch", "read";
  permission java.util.PropertyPermission "file.separator", "read";
  permission java.util.PropertyPermission "path.separator", "read";
  permission java.util.PropertyPermission "line.separator", "read";
  permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.specification.version", "read";
  permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.specification.vendor", "read";
  permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.specification.name", "read";
  permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.vm.specification.version", "read";
  permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.vm.specification.vendor", "read";
  permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.vm.specification.name", "read";
  permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.vm.version", "read";
  permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.vm.vendor", "read";
  permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.vm.name", "read";
  permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```